# How to show the ideal $\mathfrak a$ is not finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $k$ be a field and let $A=k\{x,y\}$ be the free algebra over $k$ on two generators. Let $z_i=yx^i$. Consider the left ideal $\mathfrak a=\sum_{i\geqslant 0} Az_i$. How can one show $\mathfrak a$ is not finitely generated?

I encountered this while trying to exhibit a ring $A$ and a short exact sequence of left $A$-modules whose last two terms where finitely generated, but whose first term wasn't.

Comment: You want an example of a module $M$ and submodule $N$ such that $M$ and $M/N$ are finitely generated modules while $N$ is not. Is your specific example the main point, or any example at all? If you want any example, a simpler one uses $A = M = k[x_1,x_2,\ldots]$ and $N = (x_1,x_2,\ldots)$. As an $A$-module, $M$ and $M/N$ are generated by $1$ and $N$ is not finitely generated. More generally, let $A$ be any non-Noetherian ring and $I$ be an ideal in $A$ that is not finitely generated. Then use $M = A$ and $N = I$.

Comment: @KCd Well, I knew my example would work, but I wasn't entirely sure how to prove the claim. Yes, that is the general idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to proceed as follows:

- first, your algebra is graded, with $x$ and $y$ in degree $1$, and your ideal is a graded ideal, that is, it is generated by homogeneous elements.
- If $M$ is a finitely generated graded module over a non-negatively graded algebra algebra $A$ with $A_0$ a field, and we write $A_+$ the ideal generated by positively graded elements, then the vector space $M/A_+M$ has dimension equal to the cardinal of a minimal set of generators.
- In your case, $M/A_+M$ is infinite-dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

Note that any element of the ideal is sum of elements ending in $yx^i$ for various $i$s. Now suppose the ideal was finitely generated. This means there is a largest $i$ occurring in these sums: since the algebra is free, any two different words are linearly independent and hence we cannot obtain higher occurrences of powers of $x$ to the right. But in our ideal we have arbitrarily large powers of $x$ to the right, so it must be the case the ideal not finitely generated.

Comment: (Thanks Quimey)