# Is it true that any finitely generated ring has no infinite minimal generating set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I want to prove that any finitely generated (not necessarilly commutative) ring $R$ is Noetherian.

Attempt: Suppose not. Then there is an ascending chain of left-ideals $I_i$ of $R$ such that $I_1\subsetneq I_2\subsetneq...$ Let $a_1\in I_1$ and $a_i\in I_{i}-I_{i-1}$ for all $i=2,3,...$ Then we can complete the set $\{a_1,a_2,...\}$ to a generating set of $R$. I claim that any finitely generated ring has no infinite minimal generating set. But I'm not sure whether the claim is true or not. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is a "finitely generated ring"?

Comment: It is a ring $R$ generating by a finite subset $S$ of $R$. Here, generating means the smallest ring containing $S$.

Comment: Please, add in the question that the ring is not supposed to be commutative. On the other hand, the assert is false: the ring of polynomials in two noncommuting indeterminates over the integers is not noetherian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix a finite set $g_1, \ldots, g_n$ generating R.  Let X be an infinite set that also generates R.  Then we can write each $g_i$ as a (non-commutative) polynomial (with integer coefficients) in finitely many elements of X, say $$g_i = f_i (x_{i,1}, \ldots, x_{i,N}).$$  Then the finite subset of X consisting of the $x_{i,j}$ generates R.

As for the ring being noetherian, I think this is not true.  Take $\mathbb{Z}\{x,y\}$ and consider the ideal $(xy^n x | n>1)$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** The easiest examples of finitely generated rings are $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, which you should know (or prove) are noetherian. Then, remember that if a ring $R$ is noetherian and $f:R\to S$ is a surjective ring map, then $S$ is noetherian.

You can take this as a direct argument, or adapt this approach by pulling back your work so far to a ring $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.

Comment: @ErginSuer Every commutative finitely generated ring is *a quotient* of $\Bbb Z[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ for some $n$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Yes, so I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 3):

The integers are noetherian. Use Hilbert's basis theorem in the commutative case and that rings are $\Bbb Z$-algebras.

Under the assumption that the ring is not commutative, the claim is false. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100045/how-to-show-the-ideal-mathfrak-a-is-not-finitely-generated) for an explicit example of a non finitely generated ideal in the free algebra of two elements over $\Bbb Z$.